# Google App Script - Flag mails as important

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a script to be send mails automatically based on dates,
now I need to flag the mails as important.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the code you wrote, the issue you're dealing with ?

Comment: You haven't provided any code to start from, but I think you are looking for... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#markImportant()

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and it is working perfectly fine.
The mails which my script sends needs to be highlighted or flagged as Important.

Do we have any help from GAS to make it possible ?

```
<code>
function sendEmails2() 
{
  Logger.log('OFFER EXPIRY ALERT ran!');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alert");
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var VLastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var LastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()-1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, LastRow, LastCol)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var d = new Date();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();

  do
  { 
    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(startRow,1).getDisplayValues(); // First column
    var msg1 = sheet.getRange(startRow,2).getDisplayValues();      // Second column
    var msg2 = sheet.getRange(startRow,3).getDisplayValues();     // Third column
    var msg3 = sheet.getRange(startRow,4).getDisplayValues();     // Fourth column
    var Indic = sheet.getRange(startRow,LastCol).getDisplayValues();  // sixth column to check indicator value 

     if(Indic=="SEND ALERT MAIL")
    {
    var subject = "OFFER EXPIRY ALERT";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,'Hello Team,\n\nPFB, Details on Offers expiring in upcoming days.\n\nOffer Name : '+msg1+'\nTicket ID : '+msg2+'\nDue Date : '+msg3);
    var cell = sheet.getRange(startRow,VLastCol);
    cell.setValue("Mail Sent at :"+' '+d)
    Logger.log('value of the email is: ' + msg1+' '+msg2+' '+msg3);
    }
     else 
    {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(startRow,VLastCol);
    cell.setValue("Date not reached")
    }
    startRow=startRow+1;
 }
  while(startRow != LastRow)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
</code>
```

Comment: var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
        firstThread.markImportant();